# Accessor methods for Collections in Java

Tags: java

Given a generic class:

```
class MyClass (
       private List l = new LinkedList <String>();

       public void addElement (String s) (l.add (s);)
       .............
)
```

an accessor method that allows me to iterate on the list  as it should be?

I had decided to implement a method that returns an iterator directly, but does not seem correct because it could change the list from the outside with remove ().

What do you think?

Comment: I need a method that allows me to iterate the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import java.util.*;

public Iterator<String> elements() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(elements).iterator();
}
```

If you don't mind exposing the fact that the elements are stored as a List, you could also use do:

```
public ListIterator<String> elements() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(elements).listIterator();
}
```

If you want to allow callers to use the "foreach" syntax, you might want to return an Iterable:

```
public Iterable<String> getElements() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(elements);
}
```

And, again, if you don't mind exposing that the elements are returned as a List, this last solution could return `List<String>`

Comment: Note that any modification of the underlying `List` will mess this up.

Comment: The `unmodifiableList()` method returns a view, so changes to the underlying `List` will be reflected in the `Iterable`. There could of course be problems if someone is using the view while it is being modified. If that's a concern, return a copy.

Comment: but I used the List for example. my problem is that given a general collection located in a class as I can iterate on it from outside without violating encapsulation

Comment: That's what the examples that return `Iterator` and `Iterable` do. The caller cannot use the method to remove items in the collection, and you could later change your implementation to be an `ArrayList` or a `HashSet` (assuming callers didn't care about ordering of the elements in the iterator).

Of course, if the elements being added are mutable, you might want to make a deep copy.

If you want something different, clarify your question.

Comment: My question is quite simple: given a class that contains a collection (ArrayList, LinkedList, HashSet, etc. ..), how can I iterate over them outside? Your method is right, but I was looking for something generic.

Comment: More generic how? You don't want to have to write the one-line accessor method?

Comment: I need a method that let me just browse the collection elements and preserve encapsulation, method unmodifiable ... I know but I can not use it.

Comment: If you want a different solution, clarify the question and state why the suggested solutions don't meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Most common way would be to implement `Iterable` interface but since you don't want to expose `remove` method you can follow the advice from NamshubWriter or **provide your implementation of `get(index)` and `size()` methods** (assuming your class should behave like a `List`). This will allow index based iteration.

Comment: but if the list is a linked list is not recommended to use access positional

Comment: Then you're stuck with Iterable and have to ask yourself a question:
Do you really need a LinkedList inside if you don't use position? My be using Sets is better? Or if you need a List - use ArrayList instead

Answer (score 0):

however such a thing would be fine?

```
public Iterator<String> getList(){

    return new Iterator<String>(){
        Iterator<String> i=l.iterator();

        public boolean hasNext() {              
            return i.hasNext();
        }

        public String next() {
            if(!i.hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();

            return i.next();
        }

        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();              
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the first solution I proposed in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

need a method that let me just browse the collection elements and preserve encapsulation, method unmodifiable ... I know but I can not use it.